# progressmeter is updated too rarely

Tags: xul

I have progressmeter in my XUL source code and button that I created for testing, that increments value of progressmeter by constant value.
Problem exists because **if value of increment is smaller than 4**, progressmeter won't be updated.
For example if that const value is 1, value must be increment four times, to see change on the screen. Also internal value of progressmeter's object is not updated, ie logging variable *progressmeter.value* give non updated result.
Analogously if I increment value by 2, I must do it two times to see result. 
It does not depend on max value, the same behaviours is if max is 100 or 2000.

For example:

`<progressmeter value="0" max="100" id="progressmeter1" />`

```
var pm_value = 0;
function incrementProgressmeter(){
   var value_for_increment = 1;
   pm_value += value_for_increment;
   var progressmeter = document.getElementById("progressmeter1"); 
   progressmeter.value = pm_value;
}
```

If value of *value_for_increment* is 1, I must invoke *incrementProgressmeter* function four times to see on the screen that progressmeter is progressing and also *progressmeter.value* is updated after that time.
If value of *value_for_increment* is 2, I must invoke *incrementProgressmeter* function two times. This behaviour doesn't depend on *max* attribute of progressmeter.

I wonder if it is designed behaviour, but I don't understand reason why it may be designed in such way. If it is, I would like to know why. Also I would like to know how to omit that limitation, ie I want to value of progressmeter to be increment properly by 1,2,3 values, so the user can see progress on the screen.

Comment: And your actual question is????

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question. And also the next comment in case you are asking for debugging (which it sounds like you are).

Comment: Without code, a [mcve], this question may be off-topic: : Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: *How to create a [mcve], [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: We generally try to provide answers that are tested and working. If we are going to try to verify our solution works *for you* it is *MUCH* easier to do so if we have your code to start from rather than having to make it all up. To do so, we each have to first duplicate the problem you are having then find a solution. Not having source code in the form of a [mcve] makes helping you a *LOT* more work. Without such code there is less incentive to find an answer for you.